# Retain cycle and weak property

Tags: objective-c

I have 3 classes: `Core`, `Cache` and `HttpClient`

In `Core` I initialize Cache with param `core` and after I pass `Cache` instance to `HttpClient`.

**Core.m**

```
-(id)init {
    self = [super init]; 
    MyCache *cache = [[MyCache alloc] initWithCore:self];
    self.httpClient = [[MyHttpClient alloc] initWithCache:cache];
}
```

**Cache.m**

```
@interface MyCache ()
  @property (nonatomic, strong) MyHttpClient *httpClient;
@end

@interface Core ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) MyHttpClient *httpClient;

@end

@implementation MyCache
  -(instancetype) initWithCore: (Core *)core
  {
    if (self = [self init]) {
        self.httpClient = core.httpClient;
    }
    return self;
  }
@end

-(void)foo
{
  [self.httpClient doSomething];
}
```

**MyHttpClient.m**

```
@interface MyHttpClient : NSObject

   @property (nonatomic, strong) MyCache *cache;
  -(instancetype) initWithCache: (MyCache *)cache;

@end


@implementation MyHttpClient

-(instancetype) initWithCache: (MyCache *)cache
{
    if (self = [self init]) {
        self.cache = cache;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) doSomething
{
  [self.cache cacheSomething];
}
```

What you can see, `MyCache` uses `MyHttpClient` instance through dependency injection and on other hand  `MyHttpClient` instance uses `MyCache` instance.

Is this called **retain cycle?**

Do I need to set `MyCache` or `MyHttpClient` property to be *weak*?

Thank,

Comment: Why a cache needs http client? I believe you real problem is that you are not doing separation of concerns correctly...

Comment: @Sulthan Cache has list of objects that I need to send to Server through HttpClient. In Httpclient when send is done, i call cache to clear out stored object in list

Comment: That's exactly what I am talking about, cache shouldn't send items by itself, it should only hold them. One of your other classes should ask `Cache` for the items and send them.

Comment: @Sulthan As I understand, `Cache` can ask to `Core` to send requests, right?

Comment: The correct solution is a bit to hard to explain without knowing the exact functionality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you put the logic into a simple diagram. You can see there is a retain cycle between HttpClient and Cache. I think it is best to set the httpclient property in Cache to weak will solve the retain cycle.

[image: Diagram]